# How to get the latest Detected Plane in ARCore?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

What I'm trying to achieve is to place model in front of the user without tapping on the plane. For that, I'm trying to get the latest Plane from the `onUpdate` method and then `plane.centerPose` out of it.

```
val plane = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Point::class.java).last();
universalAnchorNode = AnchorNode(arFragment?.arSceneView?.session?.createAnchor(plane.centerPose))
```

What Issue I'm facing is, most of the time It still gives me a previous Plane instead of giving me an updated pose.

What I want is to get updated pose in `onUpdate` method.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current frame.

```
arSceneView.scene.addOnUpdateListener {
    frame = arSceneView.arFrame ?: return@addOnUpdateListener
}
```

Then you can extract the plane

```
val plane = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane::class.java)
```